# ANDROID_SDK_ROOT when setting up cocos2dx 3.17.2

Tags: android, sdk, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to set up cocos 2dx on my mac. When I type in `python setup.py` it prompts for NDK_ROOT and there is no issue (the root is "/Applications/android-ndk-r20/"). But when I put in the SDK_ROOT ("/Applications/") I get the following error:

Error: "/Applications/" is not a valid path of ANDROID_SDK_ROOT. Ignoring it.

I tried moving SDK into its own directory (so the path is /Applications/SDK) but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?